# How to use jQuery Ajax in JSP?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I have written a small code which inclued 2 jsp pages and

1. `test2.jsp` --> i have made a `dropdown` in this page
2. `test3.jsp` --> displays a welcome message when the person selects an option from the dropdown ,
   he will migrate to this page without refreshing test2.jsp

for this i have used `ajax jquery`

when i click on the submit button nothing happens , please help me with this
i have also put the `org.json.jar` file in the libraries

`test2.jsp code`

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
    <script>
       function check()
       {     
$.ajax({
 url: "test3.jsp",
 type: "GET",

success: function() {
    alert("succes");
},

error: function() {
    alert( "Sorry, there was a problem!" );
}
});           
       }           
    </script>
    
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <br>
    <form method="post" action="test2.jsp">
        <select name="city">
            <option value="dropdown">select city</option>
               <option value="jal">Jalandhar</option>
               <option value="ggn">Gurgaon</option>
               <option value="noida">Noida</option>
               <option value="amrtsr">Amritsar</option>
               <option value="bombay">Bombay</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="check()">
    </form>
```

`test3.jsp code`

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>welcome</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you getting any alert message?

Comment: @Braj ..  No i am not getting any alert message , i press on submit button and it does nothing or it redirects to same dropdown page `test2.jsp`

Comment: @Masud yes i want to do the same thing , since i am beginner , so thats why i used the simplest possible example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="check()">
```

instead of

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="check()">
```

because `submit` input type call form's action that is `test2.jsp`.

Comment: thanks the `button` input type is working and it is displaying a succes message means it is calling the succes function , but it is still not displaying the `welcome` which means it is not going to the `test.jsp` page

Comment: I am not clear about you design. Are you adding these two JSPs on single page.

Comment: In `test2.jsp` i have a dropdown , and once i click the button i want a `welcome` message to be displayed on the same page without refreshing the page and message is in `test3.jsp` page

Comment: Why message is stored in `test3.jsp`. simply show it in the same `test2.jsp` at appropriate position. Are you using `iframe`?

Comment: no i am not using `iframe` ... i can display the message without it but i want to use ajax jquery for it

Comment: Spend some time on [AJAX Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.ASP) and [jQuery Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/jQuery/)

Answer (score 2):

The function should return `false` to prevent form submittion

```
<script>
   function check()    {     

    $.ajax({
     url: "test3.jsp",
     type: "GET",

     success: function() {
        alert("succes");
     },

     error: function() {
        alert( "Sorry, there was a problem!" );
     }
    }); 
    return false;          
   }           

</script>
```

Comment: just curious why do we need to prevent form submit

Comment: we want to stay on the page.

Answer (score 0):

call your javascript function on change event of drop down

```
onchange="check()"
```

and navigate through firebug and check your consol it will show you your whole  ajax request